# Determine which cell is active

Tags: excel, vba

I want to allow the user to click a button to copy information from column A, enter it in an IBM Personal Communications emulator, then, when they fill out that row of the data, press the button again to go back to column A and down to the next row.

This is what I have so far:

```
Option Explicit
Sub NextClaim_Click()
  Dim IDNum As String, Row
  Dim Emulator As Object

  ' Setting up the IBM Personal Communications emulator
  Set Emulator = CreateObject("pcomm.auteclsession")
  Emulator.SetConnectionByName ("A")

  ' Initial row that user starts macro on
  Row = ActiveCell.Row

  ' Get info from first row in column A (ex. A2)
  IDNum = Range("A" & Row).Value
  ' Pull up info in IBM Personal Communications emulator
  Emulator.auteclps.SendKeys "ret,i" & IDNum & ",m", 2, 2
  Emulator.auteclps.SendKeys "[enter]"

  ' If the last active cell that the user entered data in
  ' is not the the current row in column A (ex. A2), then
  ' add 1 to Row and go to the next row in column A (ex. A3)
  If ActiveCell.Range("A" & Row) = False Then
    Row = Row + 1
    Range("A" & Row).Activate
  End If

End Sub
```

I don't want the macro to go to the next row if the active cell is in column A when the button is pushed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
Sub Lou()
    If ActiveCell.Column <> 1 Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1**

If you want to go to column **A** as well as go down a row, then:

```
Sub Lou()
    If ActiveCell.Column <> 1 Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Cells(1).Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure. As I'm reading that, it seems like it's saying "if column the active cell is in is not 1 (ex. column A), then move down one cell and select it". But I need it to go back to column A as well.

Comment: See my **EDIT#1**  if you want to move to column **A** as well as drop down

Answer (score 0):

To determine which cell is active you can call the

```
ActiveCell.Row

Activecell.Column

ActiveCell.worksheet
```

methods that will return integers, with those you can programatically locate the active cell.

Comment: Right, but you missed the other important part. I already have in the code to determine the active cell: `Row = ActiveCell.Row` and `Range("A" & Row)`. What I was looking for, after determining if it was NOT in column A, how to get there. I got the answer from Gary's Student to use this line instead: `If ActiveCell.Column <> 1 Then`. In my last comment below his solution, I tried it, mixed with the code I already had and it works. Thanks. :)